# How can one sort an NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays containing NSStrings?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting, nsmutablearray

Is there an easy way to sort an NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays containing NSStrings?

I am sure that there must be an easy method for doing this but I can't seem to find it.

To Clarify I want to sort the first array alphabetically by the NSString at index 3 of the sub array.

Comment: What are your sorting criteria for the outer array?

Comment: First of all, you have to define how a sorting order should look like. Which array comes first? The one with more entries or the one containing a string which would be ordered first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't see anyone actually answering this with other than "use this function, figure it out". So here is some actual code that you can use.

Put this category at the end of your .h file (or anywhere and import the .h where ever you need to sort)

```
@interface NSString (SortCompare)

-(NSInteger)stringCompare:(NSString *)str2;

@end
```

Put this in the .m file (or the .m of the .h you're importing)

```
@implementation NSString (SortCompare)

-(NSInteger) stringCompare:(NSString *)str2
{
    return [(NSString *)self localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:str2];
}

@end
```

Now use the sort by calling sortUsingSelector: on the array
NSMutableArray:

```
[myArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(stringCompare:)];
```

NSArray:

```
[myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(stringCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 3):

If your `NSMutableArray` only contains objects of type `NSString`, simply do:

```
[myMutableArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, NSArray doesn't have a `compare:` selector that allows it to sort itself, so you'll have to define it yourself. I would create a category on NSArray with a method called `compare:(NSArray *)otherArray` (or something that better describes what it does) and use that with `sortUsingSelector:`.

Depending on your needs you could possibly stuff all your strings into a big array when you need to sort them, and use that instead. It could be a little less code to write.

Comment: It would seem a little dangerous to add a generic method like compare: to NSArray via a category - much better to add a uniquely named selector, or better still, use sortUsingFunction with a comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by key with:

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"key" ascending:NO];
[yourArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
```