# how to sort array of strings

Tags: iphone

I create an array with string names as shown below

```
NSMutableArray *strings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[string addObject:@"string1"];
[string addObject:@"string2"];
[string addObject:@"string3"];
[string addObject:@"string4"];
```

and I create a button. Whenever I click the button the strings are exchanged how can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one sort an NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays containing NSStrings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103317/how-can-one-sort-an-nsmutablearray-of-nsmutablearrays-containing-nsstrings)

Comment: See also [How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Looks like you do not really lack basic knowledge. You can call this method in NSArray after you add your objects:

This method is the simplest way to do your job:

```
NSArray *sortedStrings = [strings sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

More about [sortedArrayUsingSelector:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can see [NSArray class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003620) about following methods.

Sorting

- sortedArrayHint
- sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:
- sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:hint:
- sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
- sortedArrayUsingSelector:
- sortedArrayUsingComparator:
- sortedArrayWithOptions:usingComparator:

As for your problem, you can sort strings by 
`[strings sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]`.

Comment: [strings sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] i am try using this but strings are not exchanged.

Comment: Does your string look really like the above? Is it localized to some specific languages (e.g Chinese, Japanese)?

Comment: the method works fine, but you are adding the strings to the NSArray in an already sorted order.
try putting "string4" at first position then run.

Comment: try `strings = [strings sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];` as it doesn't work in-place.